# Non contact (contactless) AC or DC detection?

Tags: current-source, proximity-sensor, detection, detector, voltage-detector

I'd like to detect AC or DC current (not the current level just nothing or something => ON/OFF) in a wire with a (DIY) sensor just in contact (glued) with the wire plastic insulator.
At the end the goal is to detect if the wire transport current or not (conduction is ON or OFF) with an arduino input. The voltage could be between 5V to 24V and current around 10mA to 20A.

Is there solution like hall effect or transistors in serial with antenna?
Non invasive current loop/sensor only work with AC current!

Comment: A hall effect sensor can detect the magnetic field generated by a current in a wire. But it would be sensitive to magnetic fields from other sources as well.

Comment: Be aware that you are asking to sense current and not voltage. This means that you don't care if the wire is live but no load is connected, you will get an off reading in that case.

Answer (score 1):

buy a high permeability toroid..cut a slit in it and put a Hall sensor there:

- insulation
- very high sensitivity ( can be boosted by wrapping the current line multiple times through the toroid)
- DC and AC
- insensitive to homogeneous surrounding magnetic fields.

This is essentially a Clampmeter, yes. You can also buy a commercial one and boost its sensitivity by wrapping the current line many times. The clampmeter gives you an analog reading, but if you use a Hall switch in your custom toroid, you can also obtain an on/off output.

Answer (score 0):

GMR sensors are very sensitive. (Hall sensors are not. However sometimes they call any magnetic sensor a hall sensor.)

You can approximately [calculate the field next to a wire](https://www.fxsolver.com/solve/) in mT.

You can look for a sensitive [analog magnetic sensor](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/brochures/magnetic-sensors-selector-guide.pdf)

Then you can see what currents the sensor will be able to resolve from the data sheet information about resolution, temperature drift and noise (e.g given in uT).

My guess is you can't get it to work at 10mA, but can at 10A.

The sensor would be placed against the outer edge of standard flat TPS house wiring cable (Neutral wire side , not earth side) If you place it between N and phase, the field cancels.

Comment: GMR is a good idea but too expensive for me (same price than MCU)

Answer (score 0):

How about sensing the voltage of the wire inside the plastic insulation?

You could monitor for the change in the Electric Field, using a piece of metal
wrapped around the wire/insulation.

You could induce, via capacitive coupling, a current into the wire thru the insulation, and using a 2nd pickoff determine if the wire is being controlled by a low source impedance.

Comment: [analogsystemsrf](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/132064/analogsystemsrf) Good idea, do you have source of experiment on internet (youtube...) ?