# Non contact voltage detector vs cell phone charging

Tags: cellphone, hall-effect

We have seen one video which warned from danger of working with mobile phone when is plugged into the charger by signals detected from [one](https://www.amazon.in/Gadget-Heros-Contact-90-1000V-Detector/dp/B00PFWPEEA) non contact voltage detector like this:

[image]

[image]

So [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371604/non-contact-contactless-ac-or-dc-detection) said:

> My guess is you can't get it to work at 10mA, but can at 10A.

I like to know how much current and frequency  is going through human body in this condition, and how could be calculated?

Is this amount of current have any did effect on our body ?

Some More information about non contact voltage detector i found:

[Hall-Effect Based Semi-Fast AC On-Board Charging Equipment for Electric Vehicles][3]

But dont have any consideration for human body effects from this current.

Also don't find any more related google result by those tags ([non contact voltage detector][4]) only [this qura][5] which can not open because of my country filters ( shame on them which filtered quera!!):

I think this is not so important which is not find more result by google search, am i right?

Thanks for your attention.

Thanks.

Comment: The quora site is of no use.  It is about hall effect sensors, and only discusses them in detecting whether a flip phone cover is opened or closed.

Comment: Whatever video you watched is probably just some click bait intended to make you panic about some completely harmless effect.  Don't believe everything you see on the internet.

Comment: The VoltAlert detects Electric Field (V/m)  while the Hall sensor detects current (A) and the rest is spam

Answer (score 2):

> I like to know how much current and frequency is going through human
>   body in this condition, and how could be calculated?
>   Is this amount of current have any did effect on our body ?

The power supplies used to charge phones do not usually have an earth pin, so the output is 'floating' at about half the mains voltage. The maximum amount of current that can flow could be calculated from the inter-winding capacitance of the transformer and any capacitors that are installed between the primary and secondary side. It will be very small, certainly not enough to cause any harmful physiological effects. The fundamental frequency should be equal to the mains frequency, with harmonics reaching up to perhaps a few kHz.

I used an oscilloscope to capture the voltage waveform on the charge socket of my smartphone while charging (mains was 240V at 50Hz). The peak voltage I measured was about 25V. Here's what it looked like:-

[image]

To put that in perspective I also touched the scope probe tip with my finger while holding onto a lamp cord with my other hand, and got a similar voltage.

With a 10MΩ probe that voltage corresponds to 2.5uA peak. The threshold of feeling for AC current is generally considered to be 1mA, about 500 times higher. The threshold for dangerous current (when muscle contraction might prevent you from letting go) is 10 to 20 times higher again, ie. 5,000-10,000 times higher than the current I measured.

Non-contact voltage detectors have to be very sensitive to current because they don't make physical contact with the mains. That means they will show a response even when the available current is very low. Their purpose is to tell whether mains voltage exists in a wire or other object without having to expose the metal. If the object is properly insulated the indication does *not* mean that dangerous voltage is present.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce_Abbott but it is amazing for me which the output voltage range is between -25 to +25 , i thought it must be positive with some rippling on it!!!

Comment: I asked about that voltage waveform [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474172/typical-cellphone-charger-voltage-waveform) too.

Answer (score 1):

The risk of using a "not-so-smart" phone while being charged is if the phone detect the battery has reached full charge and stays ON  , because it has only one current sensor for both battery and phone load.

What this means is the battery could spend too long during CV mode and while getting warm at the same time and result in a higher risk of catastrophic battery failure but certainly accelerates wear.

None of these tools help here.